# How to stream audio files in real time

Tags: audio, rust, streaming, mp3

I'm writing an audio streaming server - similar to Icecast, and I'm running into a problem with streaming audio files. Proxying audio works fine (an audio source connects and sends audio in real time, which is then transmitted to clients over HTTP), but when I try to stream an audio file it goes by to quickly - clients end up with the entire audio file within their local buffer. I want them to only have a few 10s of seconds in their local buffer.

Essentially, how can I slow down the sending of an audio file over HTTP?
The files are all MP3. I've managed to get it pretty much working by experimenting with hardcoded thread delays etc... but that's not a sustainable solution.

Comment: What crates are you using to read the audio and then stream it?

Comment: None, just the standard library file methods to open the file, and TcpStream to stream the raw binary data

Comment: Without a [mcve] of what you currently have, we cannot do more than guessing. Please consider making one, including what you have attempted so far to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sticking with http you could use chunked transfer encoding and delay sending the packets/chunks. This would indeed be something similar to hardcoded `thread::sleep` but you could use an event loop to determine when to send the next chunk instead of pausing the thread.

You might run into timing issues though, maybe your sleep logic is causing longer delays than the runtime of the song. YouTube has similar logic to what you're talking about. It looks like they break videos into multiple http requests and the frontend client requests a new chunk when the buffer is too small. Breaking the file into multiple http body requests and then reassembling them at the client might have the characteristics you're looking for.

You could simply implement the http `Range` header and allow the client to only request a specific `Range` of the mp3 file. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method (by far) would be to have the client request chunks of the audio file on demand. `std::net::TcpStream` (which is what you said you're using) doesn't have a method to throttle the transfer rate, so you don't have many options to limit streaming backend short of using hard-coded thread delays.

As an example, you can have your client store a segment of audio, and when the user listening to the audio reaches a certain point before the end of the segment (or skips ahead), the client makes a request to the server to fetch the relevant segment.

This is similar to how real-world streaming services (like Youtube) work, because as you said, it would be a bad idea to store the entire file client-side.